# I have one error with Spring data MongoDB that java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: spring, mongodb

this is my spring.xml file which is I have put below with whole code there actually problem come when MongoTemplate class object created by bean it give the exception NoSuchMethod. I have also mentioned my error below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
              xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
              xsi:schemaLocation=
              "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017" id="mongo" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="Ganesh" mongo-ref="mongo" id="mongoDbFactory" />

     <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean> 

    <!-- <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="ganesh" />
    </bean> -->

    <bean id="personDAO" class="com.springjdbc.mongojdbctemplateclass.MongoDBJDBCTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoOps" ref="mongoTemplate"/>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

But I got error there is I have mention below please help me to solve it

```
    Mar 11, 2016 12:02:36 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1a93a7ca: startup date [Fri Mar 11 00:02:36 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    Mar 11, 2016 12:02:36 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
    Mar 11, 2016 12:02:45 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
    WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionServiceFactory.createDefaultConversionService()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:275)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.springjdbc.mongomainclass.MongoMain.main(MongoMain.java:14)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionServiceFactory.createDefaultConversionService()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService;
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:267)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionServiceFactory.createDefaultConversionService()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService;
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.<init>(MappingMongoConverter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:1691)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:189)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:175)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
        ... 16 more

    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionServiceFactory.createDefaultConversionService()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:275)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.springjdbc.mongomainclass.MongoMain.main(MongoMain.java:14)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionServiceFactory.createDefaultConversionService()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService;
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:267)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionServiceFactory.createDefaultConversionService()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService;
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.<init>(MappingMongoConverter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:1691)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:189)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:175)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
        ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this jar(download from below path) to your buildpath http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb/1.0.0.RELEASE/spring-data-mongodb-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar

If you are using maven add dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
```

Comment: thanks divyam its work now. well can you tell me how did you find this solution on this error so further I can be able to handle this type error. I am beginner in java so please help me